# JavaScript for() loop stops after first iteration

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, request

**DEVELOPER LEVEL -** Beginner in Web Development. Familiar with HTML/CSS/JS and NodeJS

**PROGRAM -** I have an array of Video URLs, this program is to iterate through the array, and download the Videos 1-by-1.

**PROBLEM -** The loop stops after the first iteration. **↓ THIS IS MY CODE ↓**

```js
////////// External Packages ///////////////////
const fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var path = require("path");       ////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var downloadFile = (uri, filename) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.head(uri, (err, res, body) => {
        console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
        fileSize = parseInt(res.headers['content-length'], 10);
        console.log('content-length:', fileSize);

        if (fileSize < 125000000) {
            console.log('\n', 'Downloading File');
            request(uri)
                .on('error', error => {
                    res.status(502).send(error.message)
                    reject(error)
                })
                .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${filename}.mp4`))
                .on('finish', resolve);
        } else {
            console.log('File Size Error')
            reject;
        }
    });
})

//////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

saveVids = async () => {
    sources = fs.readFileSync("local-FireStore-Cache-PH.txt");
    sources = JSON.parse(sources);

    console.log(`Array length : ${sources.length}]`)

    for (i = 0; i < sources.length; ++i) {
        console.log(`current index : <[${i}]>`);
        await downloadFile(`${sources[i].source}`, `${convertToSlug((sources[i]).title)}`);
        console.log(`download function complete`)
    }
}
saveVids();
```

**RETURNS THE FOLLOWING OUTPUT-**

```sh
Array Length : 27
current index : <[0]>
content-type: video/mp4
content-length: 160860560
File Size Error
```

and stops after the first iteration

Comment: Doesn't "File Size Error" mean there was an error, therefore it stopped?

Comment: wrap your `await downloadFile` method with try/catch if you want the program to continue running

Comment: @VLAZ  No friend, that's by design in my `if else` statement

Comment: @AvishaManik OK, if you do go in the `else` that logs that message, then your promise will never be resolved, as you just have `reject;` without calling it - it should have been `reject();`. Moreover, if an awaited promise is rejected, it's the same as throwing an exception - the execution would terminate.

Comment: @AvishaManik Is there any solutions below solved your problem? If yes, accept the answer. If no, please provide more information for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try "break" or "Return False". I will give an example to you get some Idea, Please see this and try to add to your code
[check This jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Janaka_Ravindra/dw0sh7tL/26/)

```
<button onclick="test()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

    function test(){
    let testArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
  
  for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length > 0; i++) {
    
        console.log(testArray[i])
    
        break; //or return false;
      
      //Otherwise use a condition as follwing -> comment out following code and see
      
     /*  if (testArray[i] === 5){
                  break;
      } */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code. The code stop running when `reject` is hit is normal behaviour. If there is a need to continue the loop, you need to handle what to do when error occurred. e.g. printing the error out and nothing else

```js
const fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var path = require("path"); 

var downloadFile = (uri, filename) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.head(uri, (err, res, body) => {
        console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
        fileSize = parseInt(res.headers['content-length'], 10);
        console.log('content-length:', fileSize);

        if (fileSize < 125000000) {
            console.log('\n', 'Downloading File');
            request(uri)
                .on('error', error => {
                    res.status(502).send(error.message)
                    reject(error)
                })
                .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${filename}.mp4`))
                .on('finish', resolve);
        } else {
            // console.log('File Size Error')
            reject('File Size Error');
        }
    });
})

//////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

saveVids = async () => {
    sources = fs.readFileSync("local-FireStore-Cache-PH.txt");
    sources = JSON.parse(sources);

    console.log(`Array length : ${sources.length}]`)

    for (i = 0; i < sources.length; ++i) {
        try {
            console.log(`current index : <[${i}]>`);
            await downloadFile(`${sources[i].source}`, `${convertToSlug((sources[i]).title)}`);
            console.log(`download function complete`)
        } catch(e) {
            console.error(e) // will print the error and continue the next loop
        }
    }
}
saveVids();
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are reading a file synchronously, ***make sure convert it in to array.***

```
sources = fs.readFileSync("local-FireStore-Cache-PH.txt",'utf-8');
sourcesArray = sources.split('\n');
```

now you can traverse the sourcesArray.

*Note: your text file must contain links per line.*